# Change div content depending on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json file with some data. What I try to do is get an input value and then when it matches one of the discount rules the price field should change to the appropiate price.

My JSON:

```
{
  "product": {

    "discounts": {

      "10": {
        "id": "151203",
        "quantity": "10",
        "price": {
            "price": 5.35

        },
        "percentage": 0.05,
        "unit": false
      },

      "50": {
        "id": "151204",
        "quantity": "50",
        "price": {
            "price": 4.95

        },
        "percentage": 0.12,
        "unit": false
      }

    }

  }
} //etc
```

My Html

```
<div class="quantity" id="wqs-quantity">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1">                                         
 </div>
```

And my jquery so far:

```
var qty = $('#wqs-quantity input').val();
$('#wqs-quantity input').change(function(e){
 if(qty == discount.quantity){
   $('.wqs-price .item-price').text(discountPrice);
 }
});
```

This piece of code is inside a getJSON call.

Right now the price field always change to 4.95. So what I try is that when somebody fills in 10 or 50 the pricefield change to €5.35 of €4.95...

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: It seems that your JSON is malformatted. Missing a quote before discounts and a closing brace for discounts and product. I don't know if you just copied it over wrong or if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You missed an opening " at discounts" : { [line 3]

2) Is the if-statement inside a loop through all possible 'discounts'?

Try using a loop like this one (where value p is the JSON object):

```js
    $('#wqs-quantity input').change(function(e){
      var qty = $(this).val();
      var d = p.product.discounts;

      for (var key in d) {
        if (d.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (qty == d.key.quantity) {
            $('.wqs-price .item-price').text(discountPrice);
          }
        }
      }

    });
```

3) If the discount has to be applied when the quantity is at least the quantity in the discounts (so 5% discount from quantity 10 and 12% discount above 50). Then you can use this loop (which checks every quantity threshold and saves the last one that applies):

```js
    var p = JSON.parse(data);

    $('#wqs-quantity input').change(function(e){
      // get new quantity
      var qty = $(this).val();

      // get discount thresholds
      var d = p.product.discounts;

      // the current value to fall back on
      var new_price = $('.wqs-price .item-price').text();

      // loop through all discounts
      for (var key in d) {
        if (d.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var diff = (qty-d[key].quantity);

          // check if current quantity is above (or the same as) the threshold
          if (diff >= 0) {
            new_price = d[key].price.price;
          }
        }
      }

      $('.wqs-price .item-price').text(new_price);

    });
```

(For this to work, the different "discounts" should be ordered from lowest quantity-threshold to highest.)

4) Why use an object 'price' inside 'price'? (e.g. "discounts.10.price.price" instead of "discounts.10.price")

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/ga59vbx3/11

Comment: What do you mean with "where value p is the JSON object"?? Do you have an example??

Comment: The JSON data object that's in the question.
Like this:
var p = {
   "product": { ....etc ...
};

Comment: I've made a fiddle here with your code... I don't get it :( See my fiddle[link](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/ga59vbx3/)

Comment: In the fiddle, jQuery is not activated. I'll work on your example and post an update soon

Comment: There are more things wrong with the code. The reference to the price field is incorrect, the JSON data should be parsed first and I made a small error with the referencing to the d.key (should be d[key] because it's a number). And the jQuery .change event won't fire when using .text(), so you have to do that explicitely. Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/ga59vbx3/8/

Comment: Massive thanks! Just one last question (sorry..)... Your code doesn't fall back to the original price when quantity is below any discount rule. So in your fiddle when I fill in 10 and then go back to 9 or 8 the price doesn't change! Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The original price is in the JSON data, so I rewrote it, so it will fallback on that price. See: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/ga59vbx3/11/

Answer (score 0):

Get input value inside the change event:

```
if($(this).val() == discount.quantity){
    ...
}
```

Otherwise you will always [retrieve the initial value](http://jsfiddle.net/ugm54mqr/)

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the value of `qty` once when the `.change()` listener is defined, and so that is the quantity which it always thinks exists, no matter whether that quantity changes.

You instead want to move that assignment into the function:

```
// clean up the data format first into the discounts array:
var data = JSON.parse(json_data);
var discounts = [], tmp;
for (var key in data.product.discounts) {
    if (data.product.discounts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        tmp = data.product.discounts[key];
        tmp.quantity = Number(tmp.quantity);
        tmp.price = tmp.price.price;
        discounts.push(tmp);
    }
}
discounts.sort(function (x, y) { 
    return x.quantity - y.quantity;
});

// now for the actual logic:
$('#wqs-quantity input').change(function(e) {
    var price, qty = this.val();
    discounts.forEach(function (disc) {
        if (qty >= disc.quantity) {
            price = disc.price;
        }
    });
    if (price !== undefined) {
        $('.wqs-price .item-price').text(price);
    }
});
```

Okay, this handles a lot more than your simple case. The first thing to notice is that I basically transform your JSON into some other JSON which makes the problem much easier.

After that, we loop through the dicsounts and, if the quantity is greater than the discount quantity, we set a function-local variable called "price" to the price of the discount. If that price gets set (and thus doesn't stay undefined) we then change the item price to that value.

The `this.val()` inside the function is the key thing; that says that we're going to take the value at every given loop rather than once at the beginning.